# How to move to the last active row in a Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a Google Form to insert data into a Google Spreadsheet.

Is there a shortcut to move to the last row where data is entered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Is there any shortcut to move to the last row where data is entered?"

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd>

Comment: `Ctrl`+`End` too, I would think. (At least for this use case.)

Comment: `Ctrl`+`End` doesn't seem to work, and `Ctrl` + `down arrow` does not jump to the last row where data is entered, but to the next row with a blank cell that follows.

Comment: Yes, if there's a blank cell inbetween, it will stop at that row. A workaround could be to move the cursor to a column that is always filled with data, like a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in the absence of other shortcuts:

1. Create a new column at the very left side (Column A)
2. Insert text in the 1st box (I use letter 'x')
3. Drag down to the last row of your sheet to create a column of 'x's
4. When you open the sheet, it goes auto to row 1 column A. Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> keys to go to the last entry
5. Make sure you always drag to the last row of entered values before you leave so that next time you open the shortcut works well
6. If the x bothers you, dim it with light font

Answer (score 1):

Here's my simple way of going to the last row in a Google Sheet:

1. Insert "xxx" or any other unique string of characters in the last rown of your spreadsheet (leave some empty rows above where you put the xxx).
2. Type "CTRL F" to start up the Find dialogue box.
3. Type "xxx" and hit Enter. Bingo you're in the last row of the spreadsheet.

As you fill in the last row with data, just move the "xxx" to a (much) lower row.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of gaps in the column

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd> - takes you to the far right lowest cell

followed by

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> - takes you to the far left lowest cell
( Optional <kbd>right</kbd> to the column you want, if it is not the first.)

then

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> - takes you to the far left lowest cell with a value.

then
<kbd>down</kbd> - takes you to the next empty cell.