# Quickly scroll to the last row with data in Google Sheets on a Mac

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Google Spreadsheets where I log some data with time stamps. It's getting really long. Every time I open it up, I have to scroll all the way to the bottom and find where I left off. I tried [How to move to the last active row in a Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46029/how-to-move-to-the-last-active-row-in-a-google-spreadsheets), but it didn't work.

Is there a way to quickly jump to the last row where data was entered, so I don't have to always scroll all the way to the bottom?

Answer (score 4):

this script will jump on the last empty row everytime you open your spreadsheet (or press **<kbd>F5</kbd>**)

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == lastRow) {
    sheet.appendRow([""]);
  }
  lastRow = lastRow + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
  }
```

Comment: @user194683 take this script if you need

Answer (score 3):

There are shortcut navigation keys [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en) including navigation keys for a Mac:

```
Move to beginning of row                Fn + Left arrow  
Move to beginning of sheet              ⌘ + Fn + Left arrow  
Move to end of row                      Fn + Right arrow  
Move to end of sheet                    ⌘ + Fn + Right arrow  
Scroll to active cell                   ⌘ + Backspace  
Move to next sheet                      ⌘ + Shift + Fn + Down arrow  
Move to previous sheet                  ⌘ + Shift + Fn + Up arrow  
Display list of sheets                  Option + Shift + k  
Open hyperlink                          Option + Enter  
Open Explore                            Option + Shift + x  
Move focus out of spreadsheet           Ctrl + ⌘ + Shift + m  
Move to quicksum
(when a range of cells is selected)     Option + Shift + q  
Move focus to popup
(for links, bookmarks, and images)      holding Ctrl + ⌘, press e then p  
Open drop-down menu on filtered cell    Ctrl + ⌘ + r  
Open revision history                   ⌘ + Option + Shift + h  
Open chat inside the spreadsheet        Shift + Esc  
Close drawing editor                    ⌘ + Esc  
                                        Shift + Esc
```

So maybe  `⌘ + Fn + Right arrow` and if that takes you too far to the right, follow up with `Fn + Left arrow`.

Answer (score 1):

If all the intervening cells have data then as per many answers it's as simple:

```
⌘ ↓     (Command + Down arrow)              = go to bottom-most cell in contiguous data range
```

But as you may have found it doesn't work if you have gaps in your data. The best solution I've found is clunky, needs three steps and uses all the arrows *except* down, but it gets the job done:

```
⌘ fn →  (Command + Function + Right arrow)  = go to absolute bottom right
fn ←    (Function + Left arrow)             = then go to absolute left
⌘ ↑     (Command + Up arrow)                = then back up to first-encountered cell with data
```

(It's annoying that ⌘-fn-down and ⌘-fn-up aren't supported.)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use *Filter by condition*. You probably have a date column in this spreadsheet. Use a filter on that column to define that  only the last 30 days, or so, are shown by default. Then the last entered row would always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
⌘ (Command) + ↓ (Down arrow) - On Mac

^ (Ctrl) + ↓ (Down Arrow) - On Windows
```

To go to the edge of the data in the downward direction. You may change the arrow direction to move to the edge in any direction.

Edge of the data refers to the last row (or column) of the data (or empty) block.

Answer (score -4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>down arrow</kbd> should work.

Comment: The question says "on a Mac"