# How to automatically scroll to bottom of Google doc when it is opened?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm looking for a way to automatically scroll to the bottom of a Google doc every time I open it. Something functionally equivalent to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120416/186471) would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929973/1595451) to [Move to last line of Google Document when it is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55920739/1595451)

> Try this
>
> ```
> function onOpen(){
>   var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
>   var body = doc.getBody();
>   var numChildren = body.getNumChildren();
>   var pos = doc.newPosition(body.getChild(numChildren - 1),0);
>   doc.setCursor(pos);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'm familiar with doing this automatically is to put a bookmark at the end of the document and open up that document by navigating straight to that bookmark's URL.

---

Shortcuts to go to the end of the end of the document are

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>
- Macs: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>
- Chromebooks: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Search</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

You can also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the scrollbar to jump to a section on the page. But I don't know if there's any way to do this once the Google Doc is fully loaded.

Answer (score -1):

- this script should work with Google Docs document:

  ```
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = file.getActiveSheet();
  var row = LineToScrollTo;
  file.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(row,1));
  ```

Comment: Do you mean through "Tools" -> "Script editor"? Pasting that into there doesn't seem to work for me but I've never used that function before so I very well could be doing something wrong. Attempting to create a trigger on document open doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I went through Tools -> Script editor and pasted this script, and it didn't work. I also tried nesting the script inside an `onOpen(e) { }` block, and it didn't do anything. @user0, did you test this successfully on a Google doc?