# How to emulate behavior or cmd + down arrow in Google Sheets Macros?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

If there is a column of 10 full cells in a row, and you go to the top of the column and hit command + down arrow, it activates the lowest non-empty cell.

I tried to record a macro while using cmd + down arrow, but instead of activating the lowest non-empty cell, it just activates the same cell over and over. I tried `.getLastRow()`.

How do I move to the lowest non-empty cell in a column, or how do I replicate the cmd + ↓ behavior?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. You said you tried `.getLastRow()`. Would you please show the code that you tried. `.getLastRow()` has a context for a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getlastrow) and a different context for a [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getlastrow). So whether and why it didn't work would depend on how your wrote your code. Also, `.getLastRow()` doesn't move the cursor, it just creates a target; you have to set an active range that is defined by `.getLastRow()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickly scroll to the last row with data in Google Sheets on a Mac](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106646/quickly-scroll-to-the-last-row-with-data-in-google-sheets-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getNextDataCell()`, like this:

```
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()
    .getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
    .offset(1, 0)
    .activate();
```

Comment: I see. That works. Thank you :) But that takes me to the bottom most cell with characters in it. How do I go one cell down from that?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. I'm very new to this (obviously). I just did:

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();`

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1,0).activate();`

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)